# Open Window After Button Click

Tags: python, pyqt

When i write the code below

```
def openDepartmentWindow(self):
    department = DepartmentWindow()
    department.exec_()
```

and in the constructor

```
self.actionDepartment.triggered.connect(self.openDepartmentWindow)
```

it executes and open a new window . But when i write the code below

```
self.actionDepartment.triggered.connect(DepartmentWindow().exec_())
```

it executes immediately but not when i click to button. I don't understand what is the difference ?

Comment: In the first one, you are passing the function to be executed later by qt, when the event occurs. In the second instance, you are executing the function yourself immediately when calling `self.actionDepartment.triggered.connect`. It will therefore not be delayed until the event actually occurs.

Comment: Okey I understand . Is there another way different from first one ?

Comment: @CahitYıldırım You could make a lambda: `self.actionDepartment.triggered.connect(lambda: DepartmentWindow().exec_())`

Comment: Different in what way? What is wrong with the first one?

Comment: There are no problem . I just try to find another solution @PaulRooney Rooney

Comment: Thank u @user38034 . It works.